# Check If String Starts With Any Of A Set<String>?

Tags: apex, string, substring

This is basically what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a Set of strings, for example:

```
Set<String> emails = new Set<String>{'abuse@','database@','fbl@','ftp@'};
```

I also have a list of leads, if one of those leads have an email address that starts with any of those strings I need to detect it and save it into another list.

For example if a Lead's email address is: database@test.com, I need to put that lead into a List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind is to use the String `substringBefore(separator)` method.

```
String s1 = 'abuse@localhost';
String s2 = s1.substringBefore('@');
// s2 will contain 'abuse'
```

From there, you can use the set `contains()` method to see if the first part of your email matches any of your targets. You would need to adjust your `emails` set to leave off the `@`.

This would be performed on each `Lead`, and could be shortened to a one-liner such as

```
if(emails.contains(lead.email.substringBefore('@')){
    // add the lead to your special list
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use regular expressions for this problem. I know, I know, now you have two problems. Anyway:

```
public static Boolean startsWithAny(String input, Set<String> substrings)
{
    if (input == null) return false;
    String expression = '^(' + String.join(new List<String>(substrings), '|') + ')';
    return Pattern.compile(expression).matcher(input).find();
}
```

The basic idea above is you simply search for an expression like:

```
^(abuse@|database@|fbl@|ftp@)
```

Note that `|` is an "or" operator in regular expressions, and `^` matches the beginning of a string.

---

If you want to make it more reusable so you don't have to construct the pattern each time (which consumes CPU), you can statically cache the `Pattern`. For example, if you put them in a `List Custom Setting`, you could do:

```
static Pattern substringPattern
{
    get
    {
        if (substringPattern == null)
        {
            List<String> substrings = new List<String>(MySetting__c.getAll().keySet());
            String expression = '^(' + String.join(substrings, '|') + ')';
            substringPattern = Patter.compile(expression);
        }
        return substringPattern;
    }
    private set;
}
public static Boolean containsAnySubstrings(String input)
{
    return (input == null) ? false : substringPattern.matcher(input).find();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because you have partial email addresses, you would need to iterate through the set for each email address you want to check. You'd need to do something like the following:

```
list<lead>LeadsToTest = new List<Lead>(); // <= leads you'll be testing
list<lead>LeadsToAdd = new list<lead>();

For(lead l:LeadsToTest){

   for(string e:emails){
      if(l.email.contains(e)){
          LeadsToAdd.add(l);
      }
   }
}
```